# random variable and gaussian brackets

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider two random variables X and Y with $X=[Y]$.
I want to compute $$P(X=x)$$
Why is that the same as $$ P(x< Y\leq x+1)$$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $X=[Y]$?

Comment: The most natural interpretation of $[Y]$ would seem to be the floor function, i.e. $[3.3] = 3$, $[3.8] = 3$, $[3] = 3$. If that's right, are you sure you have the bottom equation correct? I'd think you'd need to switch which $<$ has the equality part. Or, am I wrong about what $[Y]$ means?

Comment: @Montgomery. Yes you are right with your interpretation of the brackets.  Yes in case Y=x+1 is [Y] =x+1. I found this in my script. Maybe it is a mistake....?

Comment: By definition, $\lfloor y \rfloor=x \iff x\le y<x+1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties.

Comment: But it should be $x<Y \leq x+1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what to say given that you've confirmed what you intended to write, but the statement you've written is false. If you've found that statement in a book, then you've found a typo. As @StubbornAtom said, we have $\lfloor Y \rfloor = x \iff x \leq y < x + 1$; hence, $\mathbb P(\lfloor Y \rfloor = x) = \mathbb P(x \leq Y < x + 1)$. The particular error is that the inequality should be on the other side.

For a specific counterexample to what you wrote, consider a variable $Y$ that is $2$ or $2.5$, each with probability $0.5$. Note that $X = \lfloor Y \rfloor$ is $2$ with probability $1$; that is, $\mathbb P(X = 2) = 1$. If we substitute $2$ in for $x$ into your second equation, though, we get $\mathbb P(2 < Y \leq 3)$, which is $0.5 \neq 1$.

Comment: Ok thank you. It helped a lot:)